# Convert SVG to PDF by PDFLib using PANTONE colors which are not reflecting in PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, pdflib, spotcolor

I'm generating PDF by SVG using PDFLib library, and it's working as expected but not reflecting the pantone colors which was added in SVG with the syntax:

```
SVG SAMPLE PATH

<path id="path18" style="fill:#1f2b5d icc-named-color(ignore, 'PANTONE 2757 CP'); fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3269.67,2845.93 c 200.32,-200.33 525.12,-200.33 725.45,0 l -725.45,725.45 c -200.33,-200.32 -200.33,-525.12 0,-725.45" />

<path id="path20" style="fill:#bd903e icc-named-color(cmyk, 'PANTONE 4026 C');fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 981.129,2845.93 c -200.332,-200.33 -525.133,-200.33 -725.449,0 l 725.449,725.45 c 200.331,-200.32 200.331,-525.12 0,-725.45" />
```

Using  `pdfLib.load_graphics("auto", sourcePath, "");` this function to read SVG and convert it into PDF.

Expected output should include PANTONE colors on generated PDF.

Comment: Have you tried raising this with PDFLib support as a bug? I don't know if you can trace the Pantone colour property through PDFLib to see whether the problem is in the SVG loading not picking it up, or whether it's being dropped when assembled into the document maybe, or not being written into the PDF - that might help you find out where the problem is, and if you can fix it yourself. But otherwise this just reads like a bug report and I'm not sure what we can do to help you.

Comment: Very few SVG libraries and no browsers support such colours. They are being dropped from the next SVG spec I believe.

Comment: Perhaps you are better off using a unique placeholder color, and then post-processing the generated PDF to swap the placeholder color with your ICC one.